# Website Usability Testing Procedures

Tags: usability

I'm looking at this service: http://www.intuitionhq.com  It's great, but it requires the user to opt in to the test.  I'd like to find a service that I can just embed some javascript on the page and wherever a user clicks is recorded so I can find out what's most popular on what page.  Does anyone know of something like that?

Comment: You might get some good answers for this on http://ui.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the folks from IntuitionHQ - just thought I'd drop in on this. As you say, we don't currently have that functionality, but we are always on the lookout for popular features, and I'll be sure to put another check mark next to this one on our list.

For what you are describing now Mouseflow sounds like it might do the trick, so perhaps check that out. And keep us in mind for when you want to test some different designs, or if you want to compare two designs with each other (as we also do A/B testing).

Good luck with your testing, and if you have any further questions, please do ask.

Cheers,

Jacob from IntuitionHQ.